# Check how many times a file has been changed

Tags: git

Git traced all the files changed and updated,

is it possible to check how many times a file have been changed?

or one more step sort files by times they were modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log --pretty='' --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: how smart the solution....

Comment: nah. this is bread-n-butter stuff, you're just starting out, sort and uniq are fundamental tools.

Comment: lol, can you introduce a book about the utilities.

Comment: on GNU/anything say `info coreutils`.